# Difficulty in Compiling Mex and Armadillo

Tags: matlab, mex, armadillo

I am having difficulty compiling an example mex and armadillo program and was wondering if anyone could assist me. I am using Mac OS and have had successes with the installation.

code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"
#include<armadillo>


using namespace arma;

void matlab2arma(mat& A, const mxArray *mxdata){
// delete [] A.mem; // don't do this!
access::rw(A.mem)=mxGetPr(mxdata);
access::rw(A.n_rows)=mxGetM(mxdata); // transposed!
access::rw(A.n_cols)=mxGetN(mxdata);
access::rw(A.n_elem)=A.n_rows*A.n_cols;
};

void freeVar(mat& A, const double *ptr){
access::rw(A.mem)=ptr;
access::rw(A.n_rows)=1; // transposed!
access::rw(A.n_cols)=1;
access::rw(A.n_elem)=1;
};

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
if (nrhs != 2)
mexErrMsgTxt("Incorrect number of input arguments");
if (nlhs != 1)
mexErrMsgTxt("Incorrect number of output arguments");

mat D1(1,1);
const double* D1mem=access::rw(D1.mem);
matlab2arma(D1,prhs[0]); // First create the matrix, then change it to point to the matlab data.

mat D2(1,1);
const double* D2mem=access::rw(D2.mem);
matlab2arma(D2,prhs[1]);

// check if the input corresponds to what you are expecting
if( D1.n_rows != D2.n_rows )
mexErrMsgTxt("Columns of D1 and D2 must be of equal length!");

if( D1.n_cols != D2.n_cols )
mexErrMsgTxt("Rows of D1 and D2 must be of equal length!");

plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(D1.n_rows, D1.n_cols, mxREAL);
mat output(1,1);
const double* outputmem=access::rw(output.mem);
matlab2arma(output,plhs[0]);

output=D1+D2;
// output.print();

freeVar(D1,D1mem); // Change back the pointers!!
freeVar(D2,D2mem);
freeVar(output,outputmem);
return;
}
```

Comment: What's the compiler error you get?

Comment: mex -I/Library/armadillo-3.4.4/include/ -lblas -llapack example1.cpp
    example1.cpp: In function 'void matlab2arma(arma::mat&, const mxArray*)':
    example1.cpp:9: error: 'access' has not been declared
    example1.cpp:9: error: 'rw' was not declared in this scope
    example1.cpp:10: error: 'access' has not been declared
    example1.cpp:11: error: 'access' has not been declared
    example1.cpp:12: error: 'access' has not been declared
    example1.cpp: In function 'void freeVar(arma::mat&, const double*)':



??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully

Comment: Where is the `access` namespace supposed to be coming from?

Comment: That is a great question! I have been trying to figure it out, but I am unsure. I am using the example from this link: http://www.myoutsourcedbrain.com/2009/08/fast-scientific-computation-in-mex.html but I am unable to reproduce the result. Do you have any ideas on how I can couple mex and armadillo? Thanks

Comment: It looks like `access::rw` is just being used to modify normal assignments... What happens if you just delete all the `access::rw`s and assign variables normally? i.e. `access::rw(A.mem) = ` -> `A.mem = `

Comment: When I remote the access::rw and make normal assignments, such as A.mem = mxGetPr(mxdata);, I get the following error: error: assignment of read-only data-member 'arma::Mat<double>::mem'

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `access::rw`; maybe you can grep the armadillo source files for `namespace access` or something similar. There's also a couple of compiler arguments in [this](http://www.myoutsourcedbrain.com/2009/08/fast-scientific-computation-in-mex.html) blog you might try.

Comment: I have tried the compiler arguments and the access namespace is from the armadillo library.

Answer (score 1):

It does work on my system (Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit, MatlabR2013a, g++) using the following compilation command:

```
mex mexTest.cpp -llapack -larmadillo -lblas
```

where mexTest.cpp contains the code snippet you have provided. Note that for proper compilation of Armadillo under Matlab, it is required that your library paths are properly set. These can be updated in mexopts.sh or by redirecting the symbolic links in $matlabroot/sys/os/XXXXX, where XXXXX may vary according to your system (32/64-bit & OS).

Answer (score 0):

if you have armadillo set up correctly, just doing the following is enough (the code also worked successfully for me):

```
mex your_code.cpp -larmadillo
```